# when jQuery FadeOut an element, which attribute changes in css?

Tags: jquery, css

When we fade an element in or out, which CSS property is changing? Is it visibility, or display?

I want to write code with a `if` clause condition that says (pseudo):

`when the div is visible, do something`

Example:

```
if ( $('#div').is(':visible') ) {
  do something;
}
```

...but I'm not sure which property or attribute in the CSS has changed.

Comment: Opacity fades from 1 to 0 and display is either block or none.

Comment: Why not make that a proper answer @Johan? ;)

Comment: @ChrisKempen Allright, try to find it in the sea of answers ;)

Comment: Your `if ( $('#div').is(':visible') ) { ... }` code is also quite correct to detect visible elements...so what's the problem again? O__o

Comment: this code don't work!!!
I'll copy part of my code here and you can deside better...

Comment: I'll creat a new Question Because My code is long...
Please Check it if You can...

Comment: @ChrisKempen Thanks for editing... I'm not good in English... Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opacity.

You can test if by your self too. If you set a long fadeOut (ie: 10seconds), then you can open your browser console and check the values as they change.

Add the following code in your HTML document:

**HTML**

```
<div id="testItem"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#testItem
{
    display : block;
    width   : 100px;
    height  : 100px;
    background: #0AF;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function(e)
    {
        $('#testItem').click(
            function(e)
            {
                $(this).fadeOut(10000);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Then, open the document with Chrome and **right** click the div element we just created. From the menu that open choose the "Inspect Element" (If your browser is in other language, it should be the last option of the menu). Then, the Chrome console should be open and it should have marked the .

Finally, click the div element and you will see what hapens when you fadeOut/In some element.

Comment: and, don't forget to mark some of the answers as the correct. This will help other people to know if your have got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn()` will change the `opacity` from `0` to `1` (assuming the element is hidden from the start).

`display` will be set to `block` once the animation is finished (400ms by default).

`fadeOut()` does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it will change the opacity property, not the display or visibility properties, which will work cross-browser so if it's firefox -moz-opacity will change etc.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: The `$.fadeIn()` and `$.fadeOut()` functions do, in fact, modify the `display` CSS property, either to `block` or `none` respectively. This was true as of jQuery 1.10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you `fadeOut()` any element, its opacity is toggled from 1 to 0 and the display property is set to none. The opposite happens in `fadeIn()` method (display property is set to block.)